# How to query documents from a google cloud firestore collection one at a time with flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hi Im using cloud firestore and flutter. I want to query firestore in a way that i will get one by one element from the query and not all at once. Im developing a card game when the user will draw cards from a deck and can decide when to stop, so i don't want to query more than I the user needs to. Im looking at startAtDocument() that might be a solution but not sure what will be the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit a query to return at most one document, you can just `.limit(1)` to the end of your query. See the documentation on the [`Query.limit` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/limit.html).

If you later want to get one or more additional documents, you'd use [`Query.startAfterDocument`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAfterDocument.html) passing in the document you already have. The query will then return documents after the so-called *anchor document* that you're passing in.